# WordPress/CSS Menu Not Applying Hover Effects

Tags: css, wordpress, menu

I recently converted my WordPress menu to use the WordPress menu system, but now my hover-over affects stopped working.

Working:
http://codepen.io/JeremyEnglert/pen/rtFbA

Not Working (new):
http://codepen.io/JeremyEnglert/pen/aDICH

The code in the working example was prior to switching to the new menu system. I did a find a replace to replace the old navigation code with the new code, but something seems to be keeping the hover-over effects from happening.

Any ideas where I went wrong?

Comment: have you tried moving the css file from the old one over to the new one?

Comment: @nathanhayfield there's no need to do that. Updating the menu system does affect the actual CSS file.

Comment: exactly! What do you think is causing the old style not to work?